# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Network , file sharing

Tags: windows, networking, samba, file-sharing, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem that i am trying to set up the network like there is 2 Windows ( XP, win7) and my ubuntu so i trying to set up file sharing but from the Ubuntu i cant see the 2 windows pc,but from the other hand from the Win 7 i see my linux pc. I've tried to set up samba config file and a lot of variations of setting but im just stucked. Can you please help me out of this situation ?
Sorry for bad English -:( .

Answer (score 0):

There are several facets to this situation.  A good place to begin is https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384959

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) Please [**edit your answer**](https://superuser.com/posts/1338631/edit) to add more information. Thank you!